# Dockerfile installs newer python insteam of FROM source

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to make a new image for python dockerfile, but keeps installing Python 3.10 instead of Python 3.8.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.16

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

## follow installation from xtb-python github:
ENV CONDA_DIR /opt/conda

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh  \
    && /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda

ENV PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH
RUN conda config --add channels conda-forge  \
    && conda install -y -c conda-forge ...
```

I don't know much about conda (but have to use it).
It is Conda messing with the my Python or I did it something wrong?

Comment: you should also specify python version when creating a conda env : `conda create --name myconda python=3.8.16`

Comment: Indeed, Conda is taking over when you use it to install Python. As such, it doesn't make sense to use a base image which includes Python if you are going to replace it anyway.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee after few hours the only way to add another run: ```conda install -y -c anaconda python=3.8``` and I did it directly on docker image `ubuntu:focal`.